# How do we move shared file on a old Windows 2000 file server to a new Windows 2003 file server? (non-clustered)

Tags: migration

We need to migrate a Windows 2000 server that has shared folders to a Windows 2003R2 file server. We would like to move the file contents and permissions.

Comment: hmm can't believe this hasn't been answered a billion times on the internet... Google it.

Comment: It's great that you're moving off Windows 2000, but you're moving *to* 2003 R2? There's been two more releases of Windows Server since then with a third on its way. Unless there's a pretty good reason why you're not moving to 2008 R2 you'll probably be doing this again in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. This process does everything, however it requires the help of a Distributed File System (DFS) server for namespaces.

Download “Microsoft File Server Migration Toolkit 1.2”, file name is fsmigrate_x86.msi for 32Bit OS. The wizards in the File Server Migration Toolkit use Distributed File System (DFS) to maintain Universal Naming Convention (UNC) paths and to simplify the consolidation and migration process. The DFS server needed to be Server 2003 Enterprise or greater.
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10268

B. **This process is a standalone process, which does not require DFS.**

1) Download Microsoft "Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools", file name is rktools.exe. (Works with Server 2003, 2008, XP and 7). Use "Robocopy.exe: Robust File Copy Utility" and "Permcopy.exe: Share Permissions Copy". http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657

**Simple Procedure; If both the target file server and the source file server have the same folder scheme.**

2) Reboot both servers and log on the Target server as an Administrator account. Ensure the Administrator user Environment variables path includes the directory of where the “Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools” is at. Create a Batch file for Robocopy with:

robocopy "\OldServerName\F$\shared" "F:\shared"_ * /SEC /COPY:DATSO /ZB /R:0 /MIR /log:RobocopyOutput.txt /IS /IT /V

Note; Need more help with the switch see; 'http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

3) Now create a Batch file for Permcopy to copy share permissions (Full, Control, Read, and Change) from old server to new file server.

permcopy \OldServerName OldSharedDirectory1 \NewServerName shared OldsharedDirectory1

pause

permcopy \OldServerName OldSharedDirectory2 \NewServerName shared OldsharedDirectory2

pause

permcopy \OldServerName OldSharedDirectory3 \NewServerName shared OldsharedDirectory3

pause

Note; Spaces are needed between the OldServerName and the shared directory. Use “pause” to check for errors.

4) Now copy old server shared name from the registry to the new server, including any permissions assigned to those shares.
WARRING; MAKE AN ERROR IN THE REGISTRY AND YOU WILL DESTROY THE SERVER.
Run Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe).
From the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE subtree, go to the following key: 
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares 
Export the Key Shares and name it shares.reg. Move this file to new server and Merge.

Note; More information is at; 'http://support.microsoft.com/?id=125996

5) Check the work by creating a Batch file with;

tree /F /A > "Directories and files.txt"

Run the tree batch file on both servers, if the files and size are the same, assume all files copied.

Note; More information is at; 'http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/tree.mspx?mfr=true

6) Shutdown the old server, rename new file server with the old server name, check DNS, DHCP and WINS for correct server name and reboot the new server.

Answer (score 1):

Use Microsofts [File Server Migration Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=10268)

Answer (score 1):

[Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy)  will move the files and permissions can be migrated as well.  Many command line references exist as well as integrated help

Comment: if he has lots a shares to recreate then he should export the lanman shares registry key also.